# Passing decimal value to MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql

So currently my table is as follow:

```
    name      ->      type 
--------------------------------
   gameid     ->   mediumint(7)
  timestamp   ->    timestamp
  duration    ->   decimal (5,5)
   winner     ->    varchar(20)
winner_score  ->     int(1)
    loser     ->    varvhar(20)
 loser_score  ->     int(1)
```

Now, I'm able to connect to the database, but I'm getting a warning when inserting a new row to the database:

```
Warning: Out of range value for column 'duration' at row 1
```

For the duration I am calculating the start and end time and subtracting it. I played around with it by rounding it (thought it was the decimal issues) and passing it as a string, but it looks like this:

```
gametime = round((time.time() - start_time),5)
```

Tried playing around with what I have written for it, which looks like:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO scores (duration, winner, winner_score, loser, loser_score) \
         VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (gametime, red_p, red_s, blue_p, blue_s))
```

For some reason, I keep getting the error. Not sure if the `%s` is what is affecting it. On the MySQL backend, everything is good, except that the duration (regardless of the length) will always be 0.99999. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decimal(5,5)` means that it can store only with decimals. Any number with integer will always be truncated to 0.99999.

### Demo:

```
mysql> select cast(2 as decimal(5,5));
+-------------------------+
| cast(2 as decimal(5,5)) |
+-------------------------+
|                 0.99999 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                          |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'cast(2 as decimal(5,5))' at row 1 |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To make it work, you may change the column type to other precision, like `decimal(10,5)`.

Comment: I agree with what you said, but even if the gametime value is a decimal like 8.618591, it will give me problems. Even if I use the round() function to bring it to 8.61859, or 8.6186, it will still give that warning.

Comment: `decimal(5,5)` can't hold `7.18374`. It is out of range.

Comment: So my question would be then, the 5 after the comma, does not denote how many spaces after the decimal period?

Comment: I didn't get your meaning. `decimal(5,5)` means 5 digits, with 5 digits after decimal point.

Comment: I gotcha! I thought the first 5 was the number of digits before decimal point and the second 5 was the precision, so after the decimal point.